# Computing the area of a cone section bounded by a plane

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute the area of the section of the $x^2=y^2+z^2$ in the first octant and bounded by the plane $y+z=a>0.$
>
> source: Demidovich, task 2215

**My thoughts:**

I tried applying the following formula:

> Suppose $Q\subset\Bbb R^k$ is a cube and $\boldsymbol F\in C^1(Q,\Bbb R^n)$ is injective. Then the $k-$ dimensional area of $\boldsymbol F$ is defined as $\nu(\boldsymbol F)=\int_Q\sqrt{\det\nabla F(\boldsymbol u)^T\nabla F(\boldsymbol u)}d\boldsymbol u.$

I think this section, call it $S$ can be written as $\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\mid x^2=y^2+z^2\}\cap\bigcup_{v\in[0,1]}\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^2 y+z=av\}.$ I tried parametrizing each of the intersection in the union as follows:

$$(x,y,z)=\boldsymbol F(u,v)=(f(y,z),y,z)=\left(\frac{av}{\sqrt 2\sin\left(\frac\pi2u+\frac\pi4\right)},\frac{av}{\sqrt 2\sin\left(\frac\pi2u+\frac\pi4\right)},\frac\pi2u\right).$$ $\sin\left(\frac\pi2+\frac\pi4\right)$ arose from the polar equation of the line $y+z=av,$ which yields $r=\frac{av}{\sin\varphi+\cos\varphi}.$

Now, $$\nabla F(u,v)=\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{av\pi\cos\left(\frac\pi2u+\frac\pi4\right)}{\sqrt 2(1+\sin(\pi u)} & \frac{a}{\sqrt 2\sin\left(\frac\pi2u+\frac\pi4\right)}\\-\frac{av\pi\cos\left(\frac\pi2u+\frac\pi4\right)}{\sqrt 2(1+\sin(\pi u))}& \frac{a}{\sqrt 2\sin\left(\frac\pi2u+\frac\pi4\right)}\\ \frac\pi2 &0\end{bmatrix},i=1,2$$

where the partials in the first column are obtained as $\frac{\partial F_i(u,v)}{\partial u}=-\frac{av\cos\left(\frac\pi2u+\frac\pi4\right)}{\sqrt 2\left(1-\cos\left(\pi u+\frac\pi2\right)\right)}=-\frac{av\pi\cos\left(\frac\pi2u+\frac\pi4\right)}{\sqrt 2(1+\sin(\pi u)}.$ Proceeding in a similar manner, using the formulae $$\sin^2\alpha=\frac{1-\cos(2\alpha)}2\\\cos^2\alpha=\frac{1+\cos(2\alpha)}2\\\cot\alpha=\frac{\sin(2\alpha)}{1-\cos(2\alpha)}$$ I got $$\nabla F(u,v)^T\nabla F(u,v)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac\pi4+a^2v^2\pi^2\frac{1-\sin(\pi u)}{(1+\sin(\pi u))^2}&-\frac{a^2v\pi\sin(\pi u)}{(1+\sin(\pi u))^2}\\-\frac{a^2v\pi\sin(\pi u)}{(1+\sin(\pi u))^2}&\frac{2a}{1+\sin(\pi u)}\end{bmatrix}$$ but the determinant doesn't seem quite operable.

Is there any elegant way? Should I sum the length of the curves that are intersections instead?

Comment: Try looking what type of curve is defined by the section..

Comment: @LilMinho, I think it's a part of a branch of a hyperbola.

Comment: I got $\frac{x^2}{2}-(y-\frac{a}{2})^2=\frac{3a^2}{4}$. Maybe there's a good change of parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: The bounds in the $yz$-plane are $z=0$, $y=0$, and $y+z=a$, which allows the surface area to be integrated as
\begin{align}
&\int_0^a \int_0^{a-z}\sqrt{1+(x’_y)^2+ x’_z)^2}dydz
=\int_0^a \int_0^{a-z}
\sqrt2 dydz 
=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt2}\ 
\end{align}